# Calling C# method from javascript just refreshes the page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I am trying to click a button method in code-behind from `JavaScript` code. This is what I did:
Button on my page:

```
 <asp:Button ID="savebtn" runat="server" OnClick="btntoperformaction" Style="display: none" />
```

This is my script:

```
function detectop()
{
  var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%= savebtn.ClientID %>");
  clickButton.click();
  console.log('After click');
}
```

But when I click it, it just refreshes the page and code behind function not getting called. When I debug it in chrome all function executes properly.
I also tried setting `ClientIDMode="Static"` and calling with this `$("#savebtn").click();` but no success.
This is my code behind function

```
protected void btntoperformaction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "InsertValue";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SampleData", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = SampleDatatxt.Text;
    con.Open();
    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
    {
      msgadd.Visible = true;
      con.Close();
    }
  }
  catch
  {
  }
}
```

What is wrong here? Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your code-behind?

Comment: @hardkoded In Code behind I am adding some datat to the database. I have put debugger there but it just do not get there.

Comment: Share at least the event signature

Comment: Are you sure the `OnClick` value is correct? `btn**t**operformaction`?

Comment: Did you try using __doPostBack js function? `__doPostBack('btntoperformaction', '');`

Comment: @hardkoded Update question.

Comment: @Dari I tried `__doPostBack('btntoperformaction', 'onclick');` that also not worked.

Comment: Is the Button inside a UpdatePanel ?

Comment: @Dari There is no update Panel in my code.

Comment: If you change the style and click the button, does it work?

Comment: When you trigger detectop function? Maybe you need trigger in `$( document ).ready()`

Comment: @hardkoded I tried that but it not working. I am having simple `aspx` page couldn't figure out what theproblem is?

Comment: Do you have AutoEventWireup="true"?

Comment: @Dari The question isn't tagged with JQuery and no JQuery code has been shown.

Comment: @hardkoded Yes, I have `AutoEventWireup="true"`.

Comment: I tested your code and code behind function was called. Can you share your aspx complete?

Comment: @Dari I don't think of sharing aspx page. I have debugged script is chrome console it is executing properly and log after click is getting called but function is not getting called. Although thank you for taking out your precious time and your suggestion.